# Doubts about libgdx values for 3D animation

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

after creating a very simple animation using libGDX i have some questions I'd like to clarify in order to make sure I understand everything prior to start with any other development with more complexity.

I have a box created like this:

```
public  void createBaseCube(Model modelCube) {

        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        modelCube = modelBuilder.createBox(1f, 1f, 1f,
                new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);

        this.cubeInstance.transform.translate(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    }
```

As it is centered in position (0,0,0) and a want its corner to be allocated in (0, 0, 0) I applied the translation in last line.

Here is how it looks like (I added a set of tiles to have some reference):

[image: first box status]

Afterwards, I create the animation. I want to overturn the box, so it will be positioned over the white tile, and rotating over its bottom-right edge

```
public class CubeAnimation {
    ...
    <<definition of attributes>>
    ...
    public CubeAnimation (ModelInstance cubeModel, float fromAngle, float toAngle, float speed, float alpha){

        this.cubeInstance = cubeModel;
        this.fromAngle = fromAngle; //value set to 0
        this.toAngle = toAngle;     //value set to 90f
        this.speed = speed;         //value set to 1f
        this.alpha = alpha;         //value set to 0
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
            alpha += delta * speed;
            if (alpha >= 1f) {
                finished =true;
                return;
            }
            float angle = alpha * (toAngle - fromAngle);
            fromAngle = angle;

            Vector3 t = new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
            cubeInstance.transform.idt().translate(t).rotate(Vector3.Z, -angle).translate(t.scl(-1));
        }
```

Everything seems to be fine, and code is quite simple, BUT (and here are the issues) when applying the animation, the box is translated to the center again (so first translate when box was created is undone), and -surprise- although I'm passing 90f as parameter to the animation, cube only rotates 45 degrees (when I set 180, it rotated as expected: 90).

Here how it looks like after the animation:

[image]

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try removing the line `fromAngle = angle;` I have a suspicion that only `alpha` needs to be changing for this to rotate properly.

Comment: Thumbs up!! That solved the issue about setting 90f, but only rotating 45f! Thanks!! :D

Comment: It is still pending that one about the translation that is undone... :_(

Comment: Translations and rotations at the same time can be pretty tricky and hard to wrap your head around! Don't get too frustrated haha

Comment: `idt` resets the matrix to identity (removes the previous translation). Use `transform.idt().translate(...).rotate(...).translate(...).trn(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);` to add it back.

Comment: Ummm, that was the missing transformation... Tested and working!! I guess that once cube is moving over the map, I will have to save the current position in order to add it as a last action to do always. I found out that I could use transform.getTranslation(<<vector3>>) to get the current translation, correct?

Comment: @Xoppa, I'm having something weird... although you can see that I'm using exact values (1f, 0.5f, etc.) it seems that when moving the cube over the map, there must be something wrong that makes the cube doesn't match exactly on the tile (edge sizes are the same as in tiles: 1f!) look here: https://goo.gl/UD0IOu what can be the error?

Comment: @Xoppa, it seems a rounding issue. I should expect the cube to be perfectly centered after rotating 90 degrees the cube over its edge. But when doing model.transform.getTranslation(...) values returned where not (1.5,0.5,0.5), but (1.483435, 0.523225, 0.5). After few moves, that missalignment gets bigger and bigger. I solved it (dirty way) with `Math.round(currentGamePosition.x*10.0f)/10.0f` for initial position of movement (same for y and same for z), but not sure if there an official libGDX way...

Comment: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17878

Comment: That was my solution (a bit uglier, but my solution) :) Thanks once again! your are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to rotate the cube from angle `fromAngle` to angle `toAngle`

You are attempting to do so gradually by calculating the percentage completed over time, stored in your `alpha` variable.

```
alpha += delta * speed;
if (alpha >= 1f) {
    finished =true;
    return;
}
```

This part is fine for calculating the percentage as an angular-velocity multiplied by time passed. ie

```
angle_percentage/seconds * seconds_passed
```

You then get the distance between the start and stop angles in this line

```
float angle = alpha * (toAngle - fromAngle);
```

This code works for a starting angle of 0, but will fail for non zero starting points. The equation for a line is `y = mx + b`, so to correct this, you should include the `b` value:

```
float angle = fromAngle + alpha * (toAngle - fromAngle);
```

This will start the animation at `fromAngle` and push it over the distance required.

The extra line `fromAngle = angle;` changes your starting location on every iteration, so you end up with an unpredictable animation, which will be different depending on the speed you choose... I'm fairly certain the factor of two is merely a coincidence ;)

Finally this loop ends when the value is set to 100%, but never actually updates to 100%. Try this instead.

```
public void update(float delta) {
    alpha += delta * speed;
    if (alpha <= 1f) {  
        float angle = fromAngle + alpha * (toAngle - fromAngle);

        Vector3 t = new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
        cubeInstance.transform.idt().translate(t).rotate(Vector3.Z, -angle).translate(t.scl(-1));
    } else {
        finished = true;
    }
}
```